# Preventing Unnecessary Syncs in Argo CD with Multi-Service Helm Chart Repo Setup

Tags: devops, cicd, argocd, gitops

I'm experiencing an issue with Argo CD in a multi-service Helm chart setup and seeking guidance.

**Setup:**

- A single repository (`service-configuration`) contains Helm charts for multiple services.
- Each service has a dedicated directory in this repo with its own Helm chart and values (like image tags, resources, env vars).
- Each service's source code is in a separate repository.
- Our CI pipeline updates the `service-configuration` repository with new image tags when a service is updated.

**Issue:**

- Each service is represented as a separate Argo CD application, each tracking its own directory within the `service-configuration` repo.
- However, when one service is updated (and its respective directory in the Helm chart repo is updated), all Argo CD applications sync, not just the one related to the updated service.

**Question:**
How can I configure Argo CD to only sync the specific application related to the updated service, avoiding unnecessary updates to all applications, while maintaining our current workflow?

**apps manifests (using helm templating)**

```
{{- range .Values.services }}
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: {{ .serviceName }}-{{ $.Values.environment }}
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: {{ $.Values.project }}
  source:
    repoURL: {{ $.Values.repoUrl }}
    targetRevision: {{ .branch }}
    path: services/{{ .path }}/{{ $.Values.environment }}
    helm:
      releaseName: {{ .serviceName }}
      valueFiles:
        - ../shared/values.yaml
        - overrides.yaml
        - ../../../global-values/{{ $.Values.environment }}-global-values.yaml #TODO: move this back to the top when we have all environments


  destination:
    server: {{ $.Values.clusterUrl }}
    namespace: {{ .namespace }}

  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: false
      selfHeal: true
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true
      - Refresh=1m
      - ServerSideApply=true
---
{{- end }}
```

app of apps:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: legit-services-{{ .Values.environment }}
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: {{ .Values.project }}
  source:
    repoURL: {{ .Values.repoUrl }}
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: applications/argocd-apps
    helm:
      releaseName: legit-services-{{ .Values.environment }}

  destination:
    server: "https://kubernetes.default.svc"
    namespace: argocd

  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: false
      selfHeal: true
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true
      - Refresh=1m
```

example values:

```
repoUrl: "<repo url>"
clusterUrl: "<cluster url>"
environment: "dev"
project: "services"
services:
  - serviceName: first-service
    namespace: default
    branch: HEAD
    path: slack-service
  - serviceName: second-service
    namespace: default
    branch: HEAD
```

Any insights or suggestions to remedy this would be greatly appreciated!

also any suggestions to improve the setup would be appreciated.

Thank you!